# Apache Camel AWS/SQS component

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-sqs, apache-servicemix

Camel v2.8  (camel-aws/sqs)

is it possible to send messages to a shared queue using camel aws-sqs component?

I am able to send directly to myQueue but not other Queues which I have access to via SQS access policy and confirmed that it works directly via CURL

Camel aws-sqs endpoint URL and route that works looks like this:

```
from("someplace").to("aws-sqs://myQueue?amazonSQSEndpoint=" + endpoint + "&accessKey=" +       accessKey +"&secretKey=" + secretKey);
```

I need to be able to send to a shared Queue while providing a URL in the following format:

```
https://sqs.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/111222333444/sharedQueue?Action=SendMessage
&MessageBody=test
&Version=2011-10-01
&Timestamp=2012-1201T22%3A01%3A15Z
&Signature=Kl0Vki0KzvoB6Z2NUHFT7mxsurCn%2FjPHv4%2BJ8LEo7NA%3D
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&SignatureVersion=2
&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIXJMGM5GYMGSTANQ8A
```

Does Camel aws-sqs v2.8 provides this functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best option because it limits the client, but I was already creating and registering an AmazonSQSClient (to use in the route definition parameter amazonSQSClient).  I created a subclass to override listQueues to instead make a call to getQueueURL which has a QueueOwnerAWSAccountId parameter.  Here is my custom client:

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.GetQueueUrlRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.GetQueueUrlResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.ListQueuesResult;

public class CustomSQSClient extends AmazonSQSClient {

private String queueName;
private String accountId;

public CustomSQSClient(AWSCredentials awsCredentials, ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration, String queueName, String accountId) {
    super(awsCredentials, clientConfiguration);
    this.queueName = queueName;
    this.accountId = accountId;
}

@Override
public ListQueuesResult listQueues() throws AmazonServiceException,
        AmazonClientException {

    GetQueueUrlRequest getQueueUrlRequest = new GetQueueUrlRequest();
    getQueueUrlRequest.setQueueName(queueName);
    getQueueUrlRequest.setQueueOwnerAWSAccountId(accountId);
    GetQueueUrlResult getQueueUrlResult = getQueueUrl(getQueueUrlRequest );

    if (getQueueUrlResult.getQueueUrl() != null) {
        ListQueuesResult listQueuesResult = new ListQueuesResult();
        listQueuesResult.getQueueUrls().add(getQueueUrlResult.getQueueUrl());
        return listQueuesResult;
    } else {
        return super.listQueues();
    }
}
}
```

The better option would be to override org.apache.camel.component.aws.sqs.SqsEndpoint.doStart, but I am working with the easier approach.